# Combing year and month column only to make date pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I need some help I currently have a dataframe that has two seperate columns year and month in numeric format and I want to convert only these columns into a date.
E.g 12-2017

Does anyone know how to do this?
Any help would greatly be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 3):

Use `pd.to_datetime`

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    year=[2001, 2003, 2014, 1996],
    month=[5, 12, 2, 7],
    other=list('WXYZ')
))

df

   month other  year
0      5     W  2001
1     12     X  2003
2      2     Y  2014
3      7     Z  1996
```

---

**Solution**

```
df = df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month']].assign(day=1)))

df

   month other  year       Date
0      5     W  2001 2001-05-01
1     12     X  2003 2003-12-01
2      2     Y  2014 2014-02-01
3      7     Z  1996 1996-07-01
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting an error when I use the above code. The error states "ValueError: extra keys have been passed to the datetime assemblage" Do you have any advice on how to get round this?

Comment: This got rid of my error, however how do I get this to display in my dataframe?

Comment: @Harry reassign to df

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: My Current code looks like this: 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import datetime
df=pd.read_csv("Health.csv")
df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month']].assign(day=1)))
df

Comment: I've updated my code to hopefully make it more obvious

Comment: I am sorry but I'm still stuck I dont know how to make that display in my dataframe, no further columns have been added to my dataframe

Comment: You have a dataframe named `df`.  I see the code you posted.  You aren't reassigning to `df`.  I have the code above.  `df = df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month']].assign(day=1)))`